# OpenSSL request length- how to calculate size?

Tags: c, openssl

I am trying to implement a SSL client in C. As per the examples given [here](http://www.rtfm.com/openssl-examples/) (you can see the source code directly [here](http://read.pudn.com/downloads104/sourcecode/windows/428359/ssllinux_C++_example/wclient2.c__.htm)), "request_len" of input to be sent to SSL server is calculated as -

```
request_len=strlen(REQUEST_TEMPLATE)+ strlen(host)+6;
```

Can someone please tell me why "6" is being added to length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's room for the port number and null terminator.  The port is in the range 0-65535, so that's up to 5 characters.  And the string has to end with a 1-character null terminator.  So `5 + 1 = 6`.

To figure this out, you have to look at where they fill in the request.  I spaced it out so you can see how the arguments line up.  Inside the REQUEST_TEMPLATE is a `%s` that gets replaced by the host and a `%d` that gets replaced by the port.

```
request_len =          strlen(REQUEST_TEMPLATE) + strlen(host) + 6;
...                                  |                    |      |
snprintf(request,request_len, REQUEST_TEMPLATE,          host,   port);
```

Bonus info:

They then do another strlen to find out how big the request is because the port may have been less than 5 characters.

```
request_len=strlen(request);  /* inefficient */
```

The strlen is not necessary because snprintf() returns the length of the string it built.

```
request_len = snprintf(request, request_len, REQUEST_TEMPLATE, host, port); /* efficient */
```